# Synchronizing model views between QML and C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm learning QML and the communication between QML and C++ code.
In this example the views in QML and C++ should be synchronized via one common model. I've exported the model to QML. QML also shows correct number of items.
Unfortunately, the checked property is not synchronized (and no other actually) between C++ and QML in this example. Whereas two view in C++ code connected to the same model are synchronized.

What is missing? Or is it normal behavior, as probably the synchronization only one way?

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QHash>
#include <QListView>

class CppModel :public QStandardItemModel{
  QHash<int, QByteArray> _roleNames;
  public:
  CppModel(QObject *p=0):QStandardItemModel(p)
  {
    _roleNames[Qt::DisplayRole] = "name";
    _roleNames[Qt::CheckStateRole] = "checked";
  }
  QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const
  {
    return _roleNames;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  CppModel m;

  QStandardItem *it = new QStandardItem();
  it->setCheckable(true);
  it->setData("S1",Qt::DisplayRole);
  m.appendRow(it);

  it = new QStandardItem();
  it->setCheckable(true);
  it->setData("S2",Qt::DisplayRole);
  m.appendRow(it);

  it = new QStandardItem();
  it->setCheckable(true);
  it->setData("S3",Qt::DisplayRole);
  m.appendRow(it);

  QListView *v1 = new QListView(0);
  v1->setModel(&m);
  v1->show();

  QListView *v2 = new QListView(0);
  v2->setModel(&m);
  v2->show();


  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
  ctxt->setContextProperty("cppmodel", &m);
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));


  return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Model Test")

    ListModel {
        // id :cppmodel // *(1)* If this line active, this QML model will shadow C++ model with same name and 
        //                       QML views will be synchron.
        //                       However, C++ views won't be updated
        //                       If this line is disabled, Checking items in C++ models will update QML items
        //                       but QML views don't react on mouse-clicks. Obviouly, set method dowsn't work with C++ models

        ListElement { name: "S1"; checked:0; }
        ListElement { name: "S2"; checked:0; }
        ListElement { name: "S3"; checked:0; }
    }



    Component {
        id: myDelegate

        Rectangle {
            color: "green" //ListView.isCurrentItem ? "black" : "red"
            width: 200
            height: 50

            Rectangle {
                color: checked ? "red" : "blue"
                width: 20
                height: 20
                x: 10
                y: 10


                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        cppmodel.set(index, {"checked":checked?0:1} ) //*(2)* This works with QML models but not with C++
                    }
                }
            }

            Text{
                x:40
                y: 10
                text: name
            }

        }


    }

    ListView {
        id: lv1
        width:220
        height: 400
        x: 0
        clip: true
        model: cppmodel
        delegate: myDelegate
        focus: true

    }

    ListView {
        id: lv2
        width:220
        height: 400
        x: 250
        clip: true
        model: cppmodel
        delegate: myDelegate
        focus: true

    }
}
```

**Edit: Updated code. Added description in comments**

Comment: Personally I feel that the mapping from  model -> view on QML is completely broken. If you compare this to C++ only model and views. All the power of the roles are lost when working in QML since the need/usage   of the roleNames() mapping. Perhaps add a mapping to checkstate role

Comment: What is that line supposed to do : `cppmodel.set(index, {"checked":parent.toggle?1:0} )` ?

Comment: Your model does not have a "checked" property, you set a value for `Qt::DisplayRole` but have no mapping for that in `roleNames()`.

Comment: @KevinKrammer OK, chank you. I thought only user roles need explicit role mapping. I've updated the code, It still doesn't work but now I understand C++ models and QML models are pretty different. C++ models don't have set methods.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz while you are correct that only user roles need mapping, you are overriding `roleNames()` and not using the standard mapping created by the base implementation. I.e. `QAbstractItemModel::roleNames()` does the mapping for standard roles such as `Qt::DisplayRoles`, it maps that to `display`, but you are only returning the mapping for your roles.

Comment: As far as setting values goes, the C++ API does have a method for that: `QAbstractItemModel::setData()`.  That's what the `QtWidget` based views are using when their delegates edit data. If you want to have a method like the one you called `set` then you can add that as a `Q_INVOKABLE` or slot

Comment: Directly call `checked = checked ? 0 : 1` in QML MouseArea instead of `cppmodel.set(...)` should fix the problem. When `checked` property is set in ListView delegate, `QAbstractItemModel::setData()` in C++ is called.